# How to transform only the input signal source of an existing Arduino FFT source

Tags: fft

My question is one.
1. I want to FFT the unstable input voltage through the Arduino.
How do I transform from an existing Arduino FFT source?

I'm an Arduino starter.
Please give me a detailed answer.

```
/*
fft_adc_serial.pde
guest openmusiclabs.com 7.7.14
example sketch for testing the fft library.
it takes in data on ADC0 (Analog0) and processes them
with the fft. the data is sent out over the serial
port at 115.2kb.
*/

#define LOG_OUT 1 // use the log output function
#define FFT_N 256 // set to 256 point fft

#include <FFT.h> // include the library

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200); // use the serial port
TIMSK0 = 0; // turn off timer0 for lower jitter
ADCSRA = 0xe5; // set the adc to free running mode
ADMUX = 0x40; // use adc0
DIDR0 = 0x01; // turn off the digital input for adc0
}

void loop() {
while(1) { // reduces jitter
cli();  // UDRE interrupt slows this way down on arduino1.0
while(!(ADCSRA & 0x10)); // wait for adc to be ready
ADCSRA = 0xf5; // restart adc
byte m = ADCL; // fetch adc data
byte j = ADCH;
int k = (j << 8) | m; // form into an int
k -= 0x0200; // form into a signed int
k <<= 6; // form into a 16b signed int
fft_window(); // window the data for better frequency respons
fft_reorder(); // reorder the data before doing the fft
fft_run(); // process the data in the fft
fft_mag_log(); // take the output of the fft
sei();
Serial.println("start"); // header send 
for (byte i = 0 ; i < FFT_N ; i+=2) { 
Serial.write(fft_input[i]);   // send out the real part
Serial.write(fft_input[i+1]); // send out the imaginary part

 }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific about what you are trying to achieve. It would appear that the code above should do what you want - in what way is not meeting your requirements ?